# Class objects destruction

Tags: pointers, visual-c++, null, delete-operator

In the following code I intentionally set a pointer, `p`, to `NULL` after deleting it so that the second object can't delete it again. However, I recieve the following error dialog in Microsoft Visual C++:
`Debug Assertion Failed - Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead -> nBlockUse)`

[Full size image of the error dialog.](http://s9.postimg.org/903ug8pxb/Untitled.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class line{
public:
    line();
    ~line();
    int* p;
};

line::line(){
    p = new int;

}

line::~line()
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        delete p;
        p = NULL;
    }
}


int main()
{
    line line1,
        line2 = line1;
    cout << line1.p << endl << line2.p;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line1` and `line2` are both holding a pointer.

You need to understand that `line1.p` is a separate variable to`line2.p`, even though they are pointing to the same address in memory.

Suppose that the `line2` destructor is invoked first. It will set `line2.p` to NULL, but this will not alter the location that `line1.p` is pointing to.

When the `line1` destructor is subsequently invoked, it will attempt to deallocate the already deallocated data that `line1.p` is pointing to, hence the Debug Assertion.